# $.clone with ajax XHR request breaks events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, clone

I'm not sure if this is a jQuery bug (using 1.7.1) or if its meant to be this way (I don't understand why it would be like this, but whatever):

Try this jsfiddle out: http://jsfiddle.net/qFLpe/1/

Basically, I can create a block of HTML using JS, bind events to it, and then store that in a variable using `var clones = $(elem).clone(true, true)` for deep with events. At first glance, it acts as though it works fine. The elements with the bound events are wiped from the DOM, then restored from a variable. You can click them and they'll run the bound event.

**Update:** it looks like it just loses the events the second time $.html(clones) is called, regardless of whether its an XHR or not...

BUT... once any AJAX request runs... the events are no longer bound? The HTML is still there, but not the events. I'm not too sure why?? It's like the AJAX event is somehow resetting the cloned events that are stored in that variable... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$.live`, works fine then.

I don't think it's related to the `$.get`; commenting it out produces the same not-workingness, with `bind`.

See the last comment on the `clone` doc page:

> [...] but be aware that functions like .html() drop Data and Events from the nodes.

Not sure about the first `html` with the clones, though.

Comment: Oh, excellent! Thanks for that. I'll use live. Yeah, I was rather confused as to why it was working before the XHR being replaced using .html() but not after...

Comment: @Benno Me too. I wonder if it'd work without that first .html replace with the clones, using bind? Ah well.

Comment: @Dave Newton it does work using bind and commenting out the first `.html`?! http://jsfiddle.net/qFLpe/2/ What the hell! If you run the XHR a second time though it stops working from then. Maybe `clones` is an object passed by reference into HTML and is getting stripped, and then the second time its added it stops working?.. shall investigate